# OpenMP - simplest accumulator in loops gives incorrect result

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am using intel C++ compiler and running the program on 16 threads. I want the first loop running in parallel. The result of 'count' should be 30000000, I guess. However, it turned out to be something less than 30000000. Where is the bug? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>
int main(){
    long count = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp for
        for (long i = 0; i < 10000000; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: From my limited understanding of OpenMP, each operation of the loop marked with `#pragma omp for` must be independent from each other.

Comment: @C.R. What do you mean by 'independent'? What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've programmed a canonical *data-race*.  All the threads in your program are contending to update the variable `count` and there are no guarantees about the order in which each thread reads, updates, then writes the values to the variable.  Whatever you may believe C++ does not guarantee that `++` is applied atomically.

You should read on in your OpenMP tutorial to find out about *shared* (and *private*) variables, and also about *reductions*.

If you search around here on SO you should find similar questions, some of them with answers including code to show you how to do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can also direct omp to perform your increment atomically by inserting:

```
 #pragma omp atomic
```

before your count++ line.  Then you avoid the race condition described by HPM previously.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ztckdts.aspx  or https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#ATOMIC

Comment: Well one could impose atomic incrementation but doing so would, in effect, serialise the computation.

Comment: Admittedly, I haven't used any OMP beyond "#pragma omp parallel for", so I'm not familiar with the ins and outs - probably a reduction is better than atomics as HPM suggests. I assumed the final code would do something useful before or after the increment, which would still be parallelized, and the count could be atomic.  Otherwise both loops could be replaced with count+=30000000;